# Google mail not rendering placeholder

Tags: html, css, email, gmail

I hope some one can help me as this is doing my head in. I have coded a HTML form and all is ok until I view the email in Google mail, the placeholder text or the value text are not showing and it is only happening in Google mail, my code for th input is below and i would appreciate any solution to this, thanks in advance.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="LNAME" class="" id="mce-LNAME"
placeholder="Surname" value="surname" 
style="height:40px;background-color:#c7e9c8;border:0
!important;padding:0 0 0 5px;color:#000;width:140px;font-size:1.1em;"
```

Comment: Do you want to use `<input>` in an email?

Comment: Yes, my html email has a contact form requiring first name, email and surname.

Comment: I think Gmail doesn't support Placeholder attribute

Comment: So what do I use as it does not render the 'Value' attribute either?

Comment: related: http://css-tricks.com/html-forms-in-html-emails/

Answer (score 0):

I see all correct, placeholder `Surname` shows correctly, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/v4cHP/1/ What you need?

Comment: Yes same as you, i can see that but when its sent through to a gmail address, the placeholder does not show up.